# My Question is About to Store Textbox values in Arrays in Javascript And sum them

Tags: javascript

My Problem is to 
Create a webpage that allows the user to provide numbers to your program
either one at a time or as a comma separated list. The user will submit each
single or group of numbers by pressing a button. This button may be pressed
as many times as desired by the user.

I did in html and javscript but Dnt know how to accept multiple  values from text box separated by comma into javascript..

Comment: provide your code

Comment: show your code here

Answer (score 0):

Start off with an empty array to store all your numbers in and then add them using the javascript string function split.

```
var numbers = [];
var btn = document.querySelector("button");  //or any other way to select your button
var txt = document.querySelector("input");  //or any other way to select your text input

btn.addEventListener('click', addNumbersToArray, {passive: true});

function addNumbersToArray() {
    let values = txt.value;
    if (values.length == 0) return; //no data to process
    if (values.indexOf(',') == -1) { //only one value
        let num = Number(values);
        if (!isNaN(num)) { //check to make sure it's a number
            numbers.push(num); //add it to the numbers list
        }
    } else { //more than one value
        let nums = values.split(','); //this splits your string into an array
        let numsArr = nums.map((n)=>{ return Number(n) }); //turn them into a number
        let numsArr2 = nums.filter((n)=>{ return !isNaN(n) }); //filter out non-numbers
        numbers.concat(nums2Arr); //concatenate the new array to the previous numbers array

        /* COULD JUST BE ONE CALL
        let nums = values.split(",")
                         .map((n)=>{ return Number(n) })
                         .filter((n)=>{ return !isNaN(n) });
        numbers.concat(nums);
        */
    }
    processNumbers();
}

function processNumbers() {
   //DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR NUMBERS ARRAY
}
```

Definitely room to improve, but I tried to be as verbose as possible so you had the pieces of the puzzle to configure the way you wanted, you could skip the indexOf operator and just use the values.split(",") which will return an Array with only one number anyway.  I tried to include that in their just for completeness and a bit of clarity since you asked for 1 or an list of numbers.